Is Vgs affected when current is forced through drain in a NMOS?

Assuming the NMOS are ideal, talking about the left most Mosfet (call it M1), does the 500uA affect the gate voltage of M1? Because as far as i know, the Id depends on the VGS but not the other way around unless we short drain and gate and make it a current mirror. So someone please clarify about this and finally , what do the think will be the VGS of M1 if it can be determined?(Please note that I am talking only about quiescent values and not the incremental values) Thanks in advance !!!

To be clear, you're asking us to ignore the rest of the circuit around M1, which does, in fact, affect M1-Vgs as a function of Id?

@TimWilliams i never mentioned to ignore the rest of the circuit around M1. I just wanted to analyze what is happening with VGS of M1

Vgs of an M1 will be forced to be equal to the value needed to have ID = 500uA. This is what you ask for?

@G36 Yeah my question is, if ID is 500uA, what forces it to take that value .cuz i dont see a feedback like that of a current mirror which will force VGS to make sure ID becomes 500uA. Btw thank u for taking time to help.

We have M2 and M3, thus, if M1 is off the current source will "force" a large voltage at the M2 gate causing it to open more (conduct more current). And since in this circuit, we have Vgs1 = Vgs3. M1 will be open (conducting current) eventually. This will lower Vds1 and the voltage at the M2 gate as well. In the equilibrium state, we will have Id1 = 500uA and Vds1 = Vgs1 + Vgs2. Because if Id1 > 500uA --->Vds1 will drop even more. This will cause transistors M2 and M3 to conduct less current, which will consequently reduce the drain current of M1. Do you see the feedback mechanism now?

Thanks a lot @G36. I can now understand what is going on. Thank you again !!

A short from the drain to the gate is a negative feedback and such a connection does set VGS of M1 according to the drain current as you mentioned. The upper transistor on the right (say M2) is also providing a negative feedback which will help set VGS of M1 according to it's drain current. I let you figure out how the -ve feedback works in setting the gate of M1 and figure out the calculation of VGS of M1 as this appears to be a homework question.
